# My SREC file don't have line S0(content line)

Tags: arm, armclang

I use `armclang` and `armlink` to build my project and generate SREC file but I have a issue, my SREC file no have line content S0, it like:
[image]
Expect as when I use GHS my SREC file will like:
[image]
I don't find  anything talk about this in [ref arm build](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/latest/fromelf-Reference/fromelf-Command-line-Options/input-file--fromelf-).
Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: what did arm say when you asked?   do you require  an s0 record and you cant add your own?

Comment: Hi @old_timer, arm is buid OK. Sorry but I don't know which option to add to have line S0 or arm without line S0.

Comment: you are using arm tools yes?  what did arm tech support say when you asked them about this issue?